# Generating a seamless, tileable 3D noise

Tags: 3d, generator, noise

I need to generate a seamless, tileable 3D noise that looks like a detailed perlin noise. Multiple forums say "for tileable 3D you need 6D noise" without explaining how.

What I've found so far is the lib 'Accidential Noise', which provides simplex noise up to 6th dimension like I'd need it, but nowhere is explained how to generate a 3D seamless noise out of it.
https://github.com/JTippetts/accidental-noise-library

It's going to be implemented in C#, but there is no problem with me in translating from other languages.

Hope someone is able to help, thanks in advance!

Dom

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why one would need 6D noise to make the function seamless; to my understanding, it would be sufficient to implement a 3D pseudo-random function which is made tileable by wrapping the indices at the boundaries using some modulus calculation. This three-dimensional noise could then be used as a basis for tileable three-dimensional Perlin noise without any additional mechanism; when the 'octaves' of the Perlin noise are added, the seamlessnes is generated automatically as the noise values to interpolate between are repeating.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought of, but I didn't managed to rewrite a noise function I've found. The problem is that I don't understand the method of permutating the index of the selected random byte. I tried to change this one: https://github.com/keijiro/PerlinNoise

Comment: Well ok, so basically you have some three-dimensional Perlin noise and the problem is to make it seamlessly tileable in all dimensions?

Comment: Correct. It's later translated in Unity3D Color Array and used as Texture3d. And the depth information is needed, not only for texturing a cube.

Comment: And I don't want it artificially blended.

Comment: Found another page and a sample of exactly what I wanted to have. I got a seamless 3D noise and will use it till I find any other solution. Thanks for your interest! 
Source: https://www.gamedev.net/topic/680832-horizonzero-dawn-cloud-system/

Answer (score 1):

One method to solve this problem is for you to map your tile coordinates onto a torus.  Then take the torus coordinates as argument for the 3d noise function.  A torus is tilable because the top of a tile would connect to the bottom and the left would connect to the right.